# Куда мне стремиться в изучении математики (с 1-го класса по...)?

Tags: математика

Извините, но много буков...(

Я бы хотел со временем подтянуть математику повыше школьной, но после школы начинается сильное её разделение на концептуально разные направления. Поэтому я бы хотел просто для общего познания стремиться к изучению чего-то одного, например мат.анализа (интегр. и дифф. исчисления, calculus). Но так как я ещё смутно понимаю все задачи, которые решаются математическим анализом, хотел бы уточнить.

Мне хочется изучать такую математику, где учат прогнозировать будущее на основе уже существующих данных, вычисление дальнейшего поведения на основе части информации, или когда мы можем восстановить (смоделировать?) объект по его части.

Ну, например, начальная траектория даёт инфу для вычисления всей будущей траектории, цикличность поведения объектов, восстановление прожженной дыры в фотографии или оборванный фрагмент аудиозаписи, улучшение качества изображения в тёмное время (на основе похожего фото в светлое время). Или, например, прогнозирование того, что скажет человек ещё через N слов (или мог бы сказать, но... шутка).

Вот такое мне интересно. И я хотел бы быть подготовленным к реализации таких приложений, в случае чего. Резюмирующий вопрос: будет ли классический мат. анализ серьезным фундаментом для таких приложений или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Мой знакомый, когда у него спрашивают - "как мне подтянуть/изучить математику", отвечает - "математика - инструмент. выберите задачу, а математика сама подтянется". И в принципе это похоже на правду. Мой знакомый - доктор физмат наук :).

Comment: @JaminPeru Тоже верная стратегия. Причём, как я понял по себе, в любом деле. Вот, пытаюсь учиться программировать, и тоже заметил, что именно решение конкретных проблем лучше всего подтягивает теорию...

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к тематике StackOverflow на русском.

Answer (score 2):

Те задачи, которые вы описываете, сейчас чаще всего решаются машинным обучением, а там рулят матрицы и тензоры.

Впрочем, это не столько "вычисление" поведения, сколько попытка предсказать его на основе повторяющихся характерных для объекта паттернов поведения.
"Вычислением" поведения хоть сколько-нибудь сложных объектов мало где занимаются, слишком уж это неподъёмная задача. Для вычисления поведения относительно простых и хорошо формализованных систем действительно применяют дифференциальное и интегральное исчисление, но, как я уже сказал, этот подход можно применить далеко не всюду.

Comment: Спасибо! А скажите, вот например такое в голову пришло. Компы научились хорошо распознавать голос, а как они реагируют на обрывы слов? Например, какая математика нужна для того чтобы попробовать восстановить заикания при непредвиденных неполадках на вебинаре, скажем? "Пр...т дру..я, сег....ня мы с вами займ...ся...". Поиск релевантных контексту слов, а потом подстройка под частоту голоса диктора и вставка в потерянное место?) Это тоже машинное обучение?

Comment: Да, эту задачу тоже можно решать машинным обучением. На самом деле, подобные вещи - это не столько математическая, сколько инженерная задача. Т.е. нужно знать определённые методики и подходы, в какой комбинации и к каким задачам их применить. Хотя, конечно, понимание матриц и тензоров в любом случае будет плюсом.